# How to get a list of ojects from XSL

Tags: java, xml, xslt, foreach

Please, i want to know how we can we get a list of java ojects from xsl file.

this is an example of the files :

//catalog.xml

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

//In the xsl file i have:

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist" /></td>
      </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

So now how can i do if i want to get the list of all the titles in a java class?

in other words, i want to get (in a java class) a list which contains the 3 values: Empire Burlesque, Hide your heart and Greatest Hit.

thank you in advance

Comment: Thank you for your response. In fact i'm new in XSLT so i don't have much of how to resolve this problem

Comment: In order to extract those values in Java, you can simply use JAXP/JAXB.

Comment: Thank you. Please can you give me an example of code for this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try usign XPath. You can query for a NodeList of  nodes and get the names iterating through the node list

Something like:

```
public NodeList nodeListByXPath(Node xml,
                                String theXPath) throws XPathExpressionException {
NodeList outNodes = (NodeList)_xPath(xml,theXPath,XPathConstants.NODESET);
    return outNodes;
}
private Object _xPath(Node xml,
                  String theXPath,
              QName returnType) throws XPathExpressionException {
    Object outObj = null;
    XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression xPathExpr = xPath.compile(theXPath.trim());
    if (returnType == XPathConstants.BOOLEAN) {
         outObj = xPathExpr.evaluate(xml,XPathConstants.BOOLEAN);
    } else if (returnType == XPathConstants.NUMBER) {
         outObj = xPathExpr.evaluate(xml,XPathConstants.NUMBER);
    } else if (returnType == XPathConstants.STRING) {
         outObj = xPathExpr.evaluate(xml,XPathConstants.STRING);
    } else if (returnType == XPathConstants.NODE) {
         outObj = xPathExpr.evaluate(xml,XPathConstants.NODE);
    } else if (returnType == XPathConstants.NODESET) {
         outObj = xPathExpr.evaluate(xml,XPathConstants.NODESET);
    }
    return outObj;
}
public Document parse(InputStream is)  throws SAXException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setIgnoringComments(true);    
    factory.setValidating(false);         
    factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
    factory.setNamespaceAware(false);            
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource ins = new InputSource(is);
        Document doc = builder.parse(ins);    
        return doc;
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pcEx) {
        throw new SAXException(pcEx);
    } catch (IOException ioEx) {
        throw new SAXException(ioEx);
    } 
}
```

You only have to call:

```
Document doc = parse(is);
NodeList nl = nodeListByXPath(doc.getDocumentElement(),
                              "/catalog/cd/title");
```

and now iterate through the nodes

Comment: Thank you so much futuretelematics for your help. Please i have a question "is" is the input stream to which file?